# Facebook Login from subdomains (too many "Valid OAuth redirect URIs")

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-oauth

I've faced with the following problem:

I'm using Facebook js sdk for the login process.

In App settings **Site URL** is set to *"http://example.com/"*, **App Domains** are *"example.com, www.example.com"*.

In Facebook Login Settings **"Valid OAuth redirect URIs"** are *"http://example.com/, http://www.example.com/"*.

From the main domain it works just fine, but under subdomain (e.g. http://subdomain.example.com/) i get the following error:

> "URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not
>   whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and
>   Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth
>   Redirect URIs."

When I add this subdomain to "Valid OAuth redirect URIs", this problem disappears. But I have too many subdomains to list them all. **Is it possible to accept all the subdomains as valid OAuth redirect URLs? Or what approach to solve this problem can be?**

Thank you very much

Comment: There is no wildcard. You need to explicitly mention every single one of your valid redirect URIs. (Alternative would be that from the subdomain, you link to the “main” domain first, handle login there, and then send the user back to the subdomain afterwards.)

Comment: @CBroe Got it. Thank you!